# Upload iOS app from Xcode to Browserstack

Tags: ios, xcode, browserstack

The problem is that customer has bug on his device – iPad 4 mini, but I don't have this device and on simulator everything works correctly.

My colleagues suggest BrowserStack but I've never worked with that and have some questions:

1. Does BrowserStack use real devices or simulations?
2. Is that possible to upload build from Xcode to BrowserStack?

**Update:** I've found how to upload app on their's server but it seems only for unit testing and it's not possible to launch that app manually...

```
curl -u "personaldata" -X POST "https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload" -F "file=@/path/to/app/file/Application-debug.ipa"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. BrowserStack uses real devices.
2. Test scripts written in Appium, XCUITest, and Earlgrey will work on BrowserStack. To manually test an iOS app, use **App Live** (https://app-live.browserstack.com/).